# Can I lose precision going from float32 -> float64 back to float32?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

Is it possible to lose any fidelity or precision going from a numpy float32 to a python float (float64) back to a numpy float32?

I can't seem to find a case where there is data lost but everyone around me is claiming that the world will end because there is data lost.  I just need to find a document/example that proves that data is lost before I continue.

Any help pointing me in the right direction is appreciated.

Here is a typical use case I'm seeing:

```
def serialize(val):
    # val is a np.float32
    return val.astype(float)


def deserialize(msg):
    return np.float32(msg)

message = '1.23456789'
outgoing = serialize(message)
incoming = deserialize(message)
```

Comment: As in, convert to double precision and then immediately convert back to single precision, without doing any operations in between? You should wind up with the same numbers, I believe, but why would you do that?

Comment: Serialization, our serializer coverts a numpy float32 to a python float and the deserializer converts it back to numpy float32.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is a float32 then `float32(float64(x)) == x`.

*The one exception being if `x = nan` then `nan != nan`, although `nan is nan`, hence if you want to catch all you could use:*

```
float32(float64(x)) == x or x is nan
```

.

You should take care:

```
float32(1./3)          # 0.33333334
float64(float32(1./3)) # 0.3333333432674408
float64(0.33333334)    # 0.33333333999999998
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what my trials are looking like.  Luckily we're serializing strings from an instrument not decimal representations.  Example input would be `float_val = np.float32('1.2345678901234567890')`

Comment: "`float64(float64(x)) is x`" looks like a typo -- should that first `float64` be a `float32`?

Comment: Since `is` has a distinct technical meaning in Python, you probably want to change it to `==`.

Comment: @user4815162342: Except that that makes the statement untrue for NaNs.  </nitpick>

Comment: Yes but the underlying bytes are identical which is what I care about, comparing NaNs is something we do outside the encoder layer.  `np.float32(np.float64(np.float32(np.nan))).tostring() == np.float32(np.nan).tostring()
` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Thanks all, I have updated the answer further, mentioning the special case of `nan` - good spot!

Comment: @lukecampbell You could also do `float32(float64(x)) == x or x is nan`, this is probably faster (although it perhaps it doesn't matter).